# Get class that method was defined in?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Given a `MethodInfo` object, how can I get the `Type` object for the class that it was defined in?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DeclaringType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx):

> Gets the class that declares this
>   member.

Answer (score 6):

Oh... I think it's [DeclaringType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

You can get the Type the method belongs to with the [DeclaringType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx) property